# Get User class user details by using pointer in other class

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform

In some condition i need current user and other user.I am getting current user data fine, but i dont know how to get other user data.my code is

```
PFUser *user1 = [PFUser currentUser];
PFObject *user2 = [PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"_User" objectId:Objid];
```

my output for user1 is

```
<PFUser: 0x7fd3427923f0, objectId: a1P2ZZf46E, localId: (null)> {
    email = "xxxx@gmail.com";
    fullname = xxxx;
    picture = "<PFFile: 0x7fd342791950>";
    thumbnail = "<PFFile: 0x7fd342791ee0>";
    username = "xxxx@gmail.com";
}
```

but for user2 is

```
<PFUser: 0x7fd3448b8bd0, objectId: XluNx9rZdV, localId: (null)> {
}
```

Comment: Have you read the [class reference](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFUser.html)?

Comment: yes i have see but it not filling my requirement

Comment: There are methods on that object to get `username`, etc?  What requirement is not filled?

Comment: i not need currentuser username,etc... I need other user username,etc. whose objectId is with me

Comment: Ah so your issue is the details for `user2` are not populated?  I understand now.  Are you sure the users exists?

Comment: Yes ...Its in the class User

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using `objectWithoutDataWithClassName` which will return you back `PFObject` with `objectId` only. So, if you want to get the full object by its `objectId`, you can use `+ (PF_NULLABLE PFObject *)getObjectOfClass:(NSString *)objectClass objectId:(NSString *)objectId` to get back the object like so:

`[PFQuery getObjectOfClass:@"_User" objectId:Objid];`

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:Objid];
NSArray *user2 = [query findObjects];
PFuserProfile = [user2 firstObject];
```